How to repeat a widgets group when a template variable has multiple values?
I want to monitor all my services. I create a template variable called service and allow multiple values.
Then, I created the widgets with the metrics I wanted to see and added the filter service:$service.value.
It's all good as far as I chose only one service.
When I select multiple services I would expect the widget to repeat, to show me an individual widget per $service.value.
Would be great If I could do this at the level of Group so I can have a Group with all the service widgets, and when I select multiple services, the Group will repeat with all the inner widgets.

With Grafana I had no problems doing this.
How is this done in Datadog?

It's not supported by Datadog. I've raised a feature request in August 2023 via their support portal and it's not yet implemented.
Edit: Looks like this can be achieved using the Split Graph Widget. It works with template variables too - https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/split_graph/
The limitation is that it only repeats individual widgets and not widget groups.
